# How to identify & use OSType in Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, reference

In Cocoa/Mac OSX 10.6

**OSType IOSurfaceGetPixelFormat(IOSurfaceRef buffer)**

returns a type **OSType**

where can I find some documentation/reference on the supported OSType with regard to the context of this function.

What sort OSType should I expect with IOSurfaceGetPixelFormat? do you have any ideas on the various expected values from this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `MacTypes.h`:

```
typedef FourCharCode     OSType;
typedef UInt32           FourCharCode;
typedef unsigned long    UInt32; //or unsigned int, depending on architecture
```

Comment: do you have any ideas on the various expected values from this function?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The IOSurface framework seems like it was just made public with the release of 10.6. I've also been unable to find *any* documentation on the entire framework. My recommendation would be to ask on the cocoa-dev mailing list.

Comment: More info: http://cocoadhoc.blogspot.com/2009/09/hidden-gems-of-snow-leopard-iosurface.html and http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/10/08/iosurface/

Answer (score 1):

Try the pixel format type constants defined in CVPixelBuffer.h in the Core Video framework. That header conditionally includes IOSurface.h; to me, that implies that they're related.

Comment: You can create an IOSurface from CVPixelBuffers

Comment: The IOSurface returned by CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface will have the same pixel format type as the CVPixelBuffer it backs.

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind that IOSurface is little more than a friendly wrapper around shared memory. As such, IOSurfaceGetPixelFormat simply returns whatever was specified when the IOSurface was created, or 0 if no pixel format was specified.